# Using $watch on ng-repeat object while changing filters in one controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using ng-repeat to display my datasets in certain 'divs' I assigned the filtered data to a scope var called 'filteredItems'. Due to that I'm able to access the next or previous element of ng-repeat inside the `<div>` tag.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ($parent.filteredItems = (items
                | limitTo:pageSize:(pageNum-1)*pageSize))))"></div>
```

In the controller I tried to access the 'filteredItems' object inside a function which works fine until I change the page within the same function. After changing the page 'filteredItems' of course still contains the items from the former page.

I think I could use $watch somehow to manage the problem.

```
$scope.$watch(vm.filteredItems, function handelFiltered(newValue, oldValue){
  console.log(newValue);
}
```

always returns 'undefined'.